# Case sensitive where clause in MySQL

Tags: php, database

So I have a basic login form for my website. But I've been testing the website today and I discovered that if you register as 'Andy' you can log in as 'Andy' but also as 'andy'.
To fix this issue I tried selecting the username from the database and comparing it to the $_POST['username'] via ===. But with no avail so I removed that part from the code again.
This is my basic login code  can anyone help?

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

session_start();

$DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
$DATABSE_USER = 'root';
$DATABSE_PASS = '';
$DATABSE_NAME = 'test';

$_POST['username'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);
$_POST['password'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);


$con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABSE_USER, $DATABSE_PASS, $DATABSE_NAME);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    exit('Failed to connect to database' . mysqli_connect_errno());
}

if ($stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT id, password, tokens, videos FROM accounts WHERE username = ?')) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $password, $tokens, $videos);
        $stmt->fetch();
        if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
            session_regenerate_id();
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
            $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
            $_SESSION['tokens'] = $tokens;
            $_SESSION['videos'] = $videos;
            header('Location: home.php');
        } else {
            echo 'Incorrect username or password';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Incorrect username or password';
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: Based on character set and collation, non binary string comparison is case insensitive. One way is to use `BINARY` to compare your input with column value or use `COLLATE` operator to change collation in one that will result in case sensitive search.

Comment: Don't run `htmlspecialchars()` on the password since that can actually change it. Leave it as is. You're just working with the hashes and never output it anyway. And imho, you shouldn't escape/encode data when it comes in, you should only do that when you're going to _use_ the data, since different usages require different escaping/encoding.

Comment: I removed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on character set and collation, non binary string comparison is case insensitive. One way is to use `BINARY` to compare your input with column value or use `COLLATE` operator to change collation in one that will result in case sensitive search.

In your case, change your query to:

```
SELECT id, password, tokens, videos FROM accounts WHERE BINARY username = 'Andy'
```

Or use `COLLATE` like described in MySQL docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

Comment: That would solve it for 'Andy' but can you apply it for any username? Like replace 'Andy' with $_POST['username']?

Comment: Wouldn't I need to get the username from the database and store it in a variable so I can then compare them on a binary basisi right?

Comment: @dux yes, you can replace it with a variable, just like you did in your query in your post. You don't need to compare the strings with php as the query I posted is doing that for you.